# How to put more content in a box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a hard time dealing with customers requirements. 
There is a quite small box (230px x 200px) containing an image which will be overlayed by a list on hover.
Now the customer wants to have some more items in the list than would fit in the box. But scrolling on an overlay just doesn't feel right, so I need some other kind of design solution.

I know this is not a hardcore programming question, but I rely on the community's knowledge of cool js / css hacks and plugins that could solve my problem.

Comment: put your website url here or any screenshot

Comment: How about a "show next X entires" button? Or organize it per page?

Comment: Or just tell your customer it doesn't fit ;)

Comment: Just show a larger container for your list on hover. Take a look at tags descriptions appearing on hover here on SO. Adjust this to your needs.

Comment: this is a designing question, if text has to fit a box without scrolling or animation there is just the space there is. you could add threeDots or something and than show more onclick or hover and or resize the box then, but that's an animation...

Comment: Exactly as putvande said...your customer obviously doesn't know anything about web design and you should simply tell him that it's NOT possible and that should be an argument he cannot win

Comment: How exactly is this question connected with css/html/javascript?

Comment: As I said, I am searching for a css or js solution that can display much content on a small area in a cool and innovative way.

Answer (score 0):

If you or the customer can modify the amount of data that is displayed. Then analyse the size of the block, see what's the max characters it'll hold up, then modify the server script to display data accordingly. Rather than trying to fit it from design perspective which will not be a solution everytime.

Otherwise, if you really want to do it from the deisgn itself, then try to adjust the font size and spacing according to the amount of data displayed inside. This will look a bit awkward as each block will have a different font size. But if this is not your customers concern then you can go ahead and try it.

Something like this might do the job, if different font size is not a concern. I've set a default font-size of 16px.

```
<div class="infos">Some Text</div>
<div class="infos">Some Text</div>
<div class="infos">Some Text</div>

$(".infos").each(function(){
    x = $(this).html().length;
    roundValue = Math.round(x/160);
    fontSize = (roundValue>0)?16-roundValue:16;
    $(this).css({"font-size":fontSize});
});
```

You need to modify it according to your needs.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vHhjx)

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your image as background (css property) you could use hide and show to hide or display your list on hover, and use the overflow...

I did a fiddle for you, with a dummy image but it should do the trick... Let me know if it's what you want to achieve...

jsfiddle.net/mk5Tb/1/